# What is the sof zman kriat shema according to Hacham Ovadia Yosef?

Tags: shema, hacham-ovadia-yosef

What is the is the sof zman kriat shema according to Hacham Ovadia Yosef? Please provide your source.

Comment: Why the commentless downvote?

Comment: @mevaqesh The question gives no reason to think the answer isn't "3 proportional hours into the day" nor why anyone should care about ROYs opinion (did he have a unique one? how do you know?). An incredibly poor question. The real issue is why anyone upvoted...

Comment: @DoubleAA, there's no need to be rude. There's Magen Avraham and there's the Gra time (http://www.myzmanim.com/day.aspx?vars=69049767). Since ROY was the leading sefardic authority of our time it would be a good starting point for someone to follow if he doesn't have a tradition from his father.

Comment: Why isn't any of that in the question post? The fact that you have demonstrated that you could have written a good question doesn't mean you did. Saying this post is bad and that nobody should upvote it is pretty much a fact. You are welcome and encouraged to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view of R. Ovadiah Yosef (as presented in his son's Kitzur Yalkut Yosef 58:3) is that the latest time to fulfill the mitzvah of shma is 3 shaot zmaniot (variable hours) into the day. Optimally these should be reckoned beginning with dawn and ending with the emergence of 3 stars as per the view of the Magen Avraham, but in pressing cases one may rely on the view of the Gra that the count begins from sunrise and ends at sunset.

> הלכה רווחת שזמן קריאת שמע שחרית נמשך עד סוף שלש שעות מהיום. וכתבו הפוסקים, ששעות אלו זמניות הן, שאם היום ארוך, השעות יותר ארוכות לפי חשבון אורך היום, ואם היום קצר השעות קצרות, באופן שהשלש שעות מסתיימות בסוף רבע היום. אולם נחלקו הפוסקים מאיזה זמן חושבים את ג' השעות הנ''ל, שיש אומרים שיש לחשוב השעות מעמוד השחר עד צאת הכוכבים. [זמן המגן אברהם]. ויש חולקים ואומרים שיש לשער מהנץ החמה עד השקיעה. [זמן הגר''א]. ולכתחלה יש להחמיר לגבי סוף זמן קריאת שמע, לחשוב משעת עלות השחר. [ועמוד השחר הוא שבעים ושתים דקות קודם זריחת השמש]...ומכל מקום בשעת הצורך יש להקל לחשב את השעות משעת הזריחה גם לענין סוף זמן קריאת שמע